# How to use the 3rd and 4th boundary conditions in this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, partial-derivative

I was solving
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

All the boundary conditions are as follows:-

$$u(0,t)=0 \\ u(\pi ,t)=0 \\ u(x,0)=\sin x \\ u_t(x,0)=x^2$$

which was reduced to $$u(x,t)=(A\sin\alpha t +B\cos \alpha t).(C\sin\alpha x +D\cos \alpha x)$$

The boundary condition given as $u(t,0)=0 \implies 0=D(A\sin\alpha t +B\cos \alpha t)$

And here it said $D=0 \because A\sin\alpha t +B\cos \alpha t \neq 0$

The next boundary condition states 
$$u(\pi ,t)=0 \implies u(x,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty C\sin(nx)(A\sin nt +B\cos nt)$$

From $u(x,0)=Sin x$ I get 
$$Sin x= \sum_{n=1}^\infty C\sin(nx) .(A)$$

Can I say $A=1/C$?

$$---------------------------------------$$

Part 2:-

Is $A=1/C$
$$u_t(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A}\sin(nx)(-An\sin(nt) + nB\cos(nt))$$
$$u_t(x,0)= x^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A}\sin(nx)(nB)$$
$$ x^2 = \frac{B}{A}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \sin(nx)$$

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you solved wave eq.  before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving the so-called wave equation. After separating variables we obtain for the space-dependent part

$X(x) = C\sin\alpha x + D\cos\alpha x$.

The first boundary condition yields $X(0) = 0$, and results in $D=0$. The second boundary condition becomes $X(\pi) = 0$ and leads to $C\sin\alpha\pi = 0$. If $B=0$, then the solution is trivial, i.e. $X \equiv 0$. In order to find non-trivial solution, we let $\sin\alpha \pi = 0$ or $\alpha \pi = \pi n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This results in $\alpha = n$ and, thus,

$X(x) = C\sin nx$.

The solution of the temporal equation becomes

$T(t) = A\sin nt + B\cos nt$,

and the overall solution now reads

$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin nx(A_n\sin nt + B_n\cos nt)$,

where we have absorbed constant $C$ in $A_n$ and $B_n$. Now we apply initial conditions. The first gives

$u(x, 0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin nx = \sin x$,

which requires $B_n=1$ and $n=1$ (only one term from the sum survives). The last condition yields

$u_t(x, 0) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty A_nn\sin nx = x^2$,

where the constant $A_n$ can be related to the coefficient in the sine series. We assume that $x\in[0, \pi]$, then

$A_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\int_0^\pi dxx^2\sin nx$,

and the final solution reads

$u(x,t) = \sin x\cos t + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin nx\sin nt$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something went wrong.  If $u(x,t)=\sin(x)\cos(t)$, $u_t(x,t)=-\sin(x)\sin(t)$ and thus $u_t(x,0)=0\ne x^2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: you are right, I have just deduced the interval of definition from boundary conditions.

Comment: So @Pavel is $A_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\int_0^\pi dx\sin nx (x^2 + \sin x\sin t)$ ?

Comment: @S.Dan: no, just $A_n = \frac{2}{\pi n}\int_0^\pi dx (x^2)\sin nx $.